# Ajax Progress Bar

Tags: php, ajax, progress-bar

I am building a file uploader and execute in my project. First it uploads a invoice PDF file, after upload is complete, I extract all pdf text and them I do a series of queries to store some information in mysql. Some PDF is about 40~70 pages, so it take some time to process everything, I already have the upload system with progress bar, now I want to do a second progress bar that show the pdf extract informations. Can someone give me a suggestion how to do it? 
It's php project.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few ways to approach this.

**Ajax polling**

You can upload the file and set the job's progress in a database.
After the file is uploaded you ajax a page which reads the progress from the database.

**Without Ajax polling**

You can also do this with streaming ,This article is a great place to start.
[ajax-based-streaming-without-polling](http://www.binarytides.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/)

Comment: By ajax polling you mean create a new field in database for status progress, and update by querys in the midle of process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax polling as mentioned by @anvanza. Or you can twist your logic. 
First you upload all files. Write a callback in files upload function, which initiated another ajax request, which will do all post upload file processing(extracting data from pdf, adding data to database,etc). While the second request in process, you can show the progressbar. Once the second request completes its processing, you can hide the progressbar on successful response from second ajax request.

Hope this logic will help you.